# Placing texture on Collada

Tags: collada, dae, blender

I have the following DAE file, handmade (pyramid with no bottom). Uncomment two triangles to make it pyramid with bottom:

It shows a pyramid and tries to put a texture on it. It is displayed both on inner and outer sides of a pyramid (if the pyramid has bottom, it displays texture both on sides and bottom).

I only want it on sides - not on bottom, and ou outer side of these sides, not inside.

Could you please help?

I guess there are multiple possible solutions: I would go for making the texture of two parts - one for inner and one for outer side of a pyramid, like 1280x640. This way a left half of an image will be stretched over inner side of a pyramid, and right part - over the outer part of a pyramid. The question is, how to map such a texture to this pyramid?
A working example would be great, a working example with explanation even better.

The only thing, I am going to GENERATE this DAE, so if you suggest changes, PLEASE keep them to minimum :)

Thank you.

```
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
    <asset>
        <created>2023-11-27T12:48:14</created>
        <modified>2023-11-27T12:48:14</modified>
        <unit meter="1.0" name="meter" />
        <up_axis>Y_UP</up_axis>
    </asset>

    <library_images>
        <image id="texture0" name="texture">
            <init_from>../maps/perfect_texture.png</init_from>
        </image>
    </library_images>

    <library_effects>
        <effect id="effect0">
            <profile_COMMON>
                <newparam sid="surface0">
                    <surface type="2D">
                        <init_from>texture0</init_from>
                    </surface>
                </newparam>
                <newparam sid="sampler0">
                    <sampler2D>
                        <source>surface0</source>
                    </sampler2D>
                </newparam>
                <technique sid="common">
                    <phong>
                        <diffuse>
                        <texture texture="sampler0" texcoord="UVSET0" />
                        </diffuse>
                    </phong>
                </technique>
            </profile_COMMON>
        </effect>
    </library_effects>

    <library_materials>
        <material id="material0">
            <instance_effect url="#effect0" />
        </material>
    </library_materials>

    <library_geometries>
        <geometry id="shape0">
            <mesh>
                <source id="positions">
                    <float_array id="positions-array" count="15">
                        0 1 0
                        0 0 0
                        1 0 0
                        1 1 0

                        0.5 0.5 1
                    </float_array>
                    <technique_common>
                        <accessor count="5" source="#positions-array" stride="3">
                        <param name="X" type="float" />
                        <param name="Y" type="float" />
                        <param name="Z" type="float" />
                        </accessor>
                    </technique_common>
                </source>

                <source id="normals">
                <float_array id="normals-array" count="15">
                    0.0 0.0 -1.0
                    0.0 0.0 -1.0
                    0.0 0.0 -1.0
                    0.0 0.0 -1.0
                    0.0 0.0  1.0  <!-- Normals for the sides of the pyramid -->
                </float_array>
                <technique_common>
                    <accessor count="5" source="#normals-array" stride="3">
                    <param name="X" type="float" />
                    <param name="Y" type="float" />
                    <param name="Z" type="float" />
                    </accessor>
                </technique_common>
                </source>

                <source id="uv-source">
                    <float_array id="uv-float-array" count="10">
                        0.0 0.0
                        1.0 0.0
                        0.0 1.0
                        1.0 1.0
                        0.5 0.5
                    </float_array>
                    <technique_common>
                        <accessor source="#uv-float-array" count="5" stride="2">
                        <param name="S" type="float"/>
                        <param name="T" type="float"/>
                        </accessor>
                    </technique_common>
                </source>

                <vertices id="verts-array-vertices">
                    <input semantic="POSITION" source="#positions" />
                    <input semantic="NORMAL" source="#normals" />
                    <input semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#uv-source" />
                </vertices>

                <triangles count="6" material="material0">
                    <input offset="0" semantic="VERTEX" source="#verts-array-vertices" />
                    <p>
                        <!-- 0 1 2 
                        0 2 3 -->

                        0 4 3
                        3 4 2
                        2 4 1
                        1 4 0
                    </p>
                </triangles>
            </mesh>
        </geometry>
    </library_geometries>

    <library_visual_scenes>
        <visual_scene id="scene0">
        <node name="node0">
            <instance_geometry url="#shape0">
            <bind_material>
                <technique_common>
                <instance_material symbol="material0" target="#material0">
                    <bind_vertex_input semantic="TEXCOORD" input_semantic="TEXCOORD" />
                </instance_material>
                </technique_common>
            </bind_material>
            </instance_geometry>
        </node>
        </visual_scene>
    </library_visual_scenes>

    <scene>
        <instance_visual_scene url="#scene0" />
    </scene>
</COLLADA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a curated pyramid. As usual, I will put complete explanations with examples at [robotics.snowcron.com](https://robotics.snowcron.com), within few days :)

Things to keep in mind:

1. mesh sources (...) can be in any units, so you can use meters etc. For example, 0 1 1 is ok, but 0 2 2 is ok too. Depends on the size of your object.
2. However, UV mapping (...) should be within 0-1, so for your image, you need to recalculate something like

   for v in mesh.vertices:
   uvs.append([(v[0] - x_min) / (x_max - x_min), (v[1](https://robotics.snowcron.com) - y_min) / (y_max - y_min)])

Here it is:

```
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
    <asset>
        <created>2023-11-27T12:48:14</created>
        <modified>2023-11-27T12:48:14</modified>
        <unit meter="1.0" name="meter" />
        <up_axis>Y_UP</up_axis>
    </asset>

    <library_images>
        <image id="texture0" name="texture">
            <init_from>../maps/perfect_texture_01.png</init_from>
        </image>
    </library_images>

    <library_effects>
        <effect id="effect0">
            <profile_COMMON>
                <newparam sid="surface0">
                    <surface type="2D">
                        <init_from>texture0</init_from>
                    </surface>
                </newparam>
                <newparam sid="sampler0">
                    <sampler2D>
                        <source>surface0</source>
                    </sampler2D>
                </newparam>
                <technique sid="common">
                    <phong>
                        <diffuse>
                            <texture texture="sampler0" texcoord="UVSET0" />
                        </diffuse>
                    </phong>
                </technique>
            </profile_COMMON>
        </effect>
    </library_effects>

    <library_materials>
        <material id="material0">
            <instance_effect url="#effect0" />
        </material>
    </library_materials>

    <library_geometries>
        <geometry id="shape0">
            <mesh>
                <source id="positions">
                    <float_array id="positions-array" count="15">
                        0 1 0
                        1 1 0
                        1 0 0
                        0 0 0

                        0.5 0.5 1
                    </float_array>
                    <technique_common>
                        <accessor count="5" source="#positions-array" stride="3">
                        <param name="X" type="float" />
                        <param name="Y" type="float" />
                        <param name="Z" type="float" />
                        </accessor>
                    </technique_common>
                </source>

                <source id="normals">
                    <float_array id="normals-array" count="15">
                        0.0 0.0 -1.0
                        0.0 0.0 -1.0
                        0.0 0.0 -1.0
                        0.0 0.0 -1.0
                        0.0 0.0  1.0
                    </float_array>
                    <technique_common>
                        <accessor count="5" source="#normals-array" stride="3">
                        <param name="X" type="float" />
                        <param name="Y" type="float" />
                        <param name="Z" type="float" />
                        </accessor>
                    </technique_common>
                </source>

                <source id="uv-source">
                    <float_array id="uv-float-array" count="10">
                        0.0 1.0
                        1.0 1.0
                        1.0 0.0
                        0.0 0.0
                        0.5 0.5
                    </float_array>
                    <technique_common>
                        <accessor source="#uv-float-array" count="5" stride="2">
                        <param name="S" type="float"/>
                        <param name="T" type="float"/>
                        </accessor>
                    </technique_common>
                </source>

                <vertices id="verts-array-vertices">
                    <input semantic="POSITION" source="#positions" />
                    <input semantic="NORMAL" source="#normals" />
                    <input semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#uv-source" />
                </vertices>

                <triangles count="6" material="material0">
                    <input offset="0" semantic="VERTEX" source="#verts-array-vertices" />
                    <p>
                        <!-- 0 1 2 
                        0 2 3 -->

                        0 4 3
                        3 4 2
                        2 4 1
                        1 4 0
                    </p>
                </triangles>
            </mesh>
        </geometry>
    </library_geometries>

    <library_visual_scenes>
        <visual_scene id="scene0">
        <node name="node0">
            <instance_geometry url="#shape0">
                <bind_material>
                    <technique_common>
                        <instance_material symbol="material0" target="#material0">
                            <bind_vertex_input semantic="TEXCOORD" input_semantic="TEXCOORD" />
                        </instance_material>
                    </technique_common>
                </bind_material>
            </instance_geometry>
        </node>
        </visual_scene>
    </library_visual_scenes>

    <scene>
        <instance_visual_scene url="#scene0" />
    </scene>
</COLLADA>
```

[image]